# How to convert from base64 to ascii in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, ascii

Im trying to Decode Base 64 to Ascii in python without using the built in decode function. I was able to encode from Ascii to Base 64, however im having difficulty getting back. Below is my encode process.

```
#table to allow Base 64 Conversion
b64_table ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/"

#define variables
number = 0
numchar = 0
code = 0

#get user input
user_input = input("Input")

#loop while there is user input, ASCII -> integer
for char in user_input:
    numchar = numchar + 1
    if numchar == 1:
        number = ord(char)
    elif numchar > 1:
        number = ord(char) + (number << 8)
    #integer -> base 64
    if numchar == 3:
        i=3
        for i in (3,2,1,0):
            code = number  >> (6 * i )
            print(b64_table[int(code)]),
            #prints on one line
            number = number - (code  << (6 * i))
        numchar = 0
        #works for 3 letter multiples
```

Comment: Would you please tell us why you are trying to do this? What is wrong with `base64`?

Comment: Also, if you want help with the decoding process you _need_ to show us your code for the decoding process; showing us your encoder isn't very useful.